# Entity Framework error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In Visual Studio Code I am creating a Web-Api written in C # and I am using various functions that the Entity Framework offers such as the DbContextOption and Dbset, but when I use `dotnet build` I get the following messages:

> Error CS0246: Namespace or type name 'Dbset <>' not found (is a using
> directive or assembly reference missing?) Error CS0246: The name of
> the type or namespace 'DbContextOption <>' was not found (is a using
> directive or assembly reference missing?)

This is the file where the error occurs:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Data;
namespace web_api_db.Models{
public class Conexion : DbContext{
    public Conexion(DbContextOption<Conexion> options) : base (options){}
        public Dbset<Medicine> Medicine {get;set;}
    }
 }
```

And this is the csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.tools" Version="5.0.9">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers" Version="2.2.8" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Looks like a typo: Wrong: `DbContextOption`, correct: `DbContextOptions` - note the "s" at the end of the class name and `Dbset` vs `DbSet`. You should see this error in visual studio too and not only when running dotnet build. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptions?view=efcore-5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's `DbSet` with a capital `S`.
2. It's `DbContextOptions` with plural form.